# "Normally closed" switch with NPN transistors

Tags: transistors, switches, npn

Is it possible to have "Normally closed" switch with NPN transistor when the voltage at the base is 0V? So far I only managed to achieve this result with NPN transistor when the base is HIGH. When the base is LOW it's "open" and outputting 1.8V as in provided image below and this is not what I'm expecting. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have "Normally open" switch with NPN transistor when the voltage at the base is 0V?

I suspect that you are confused with your terminology. A normally open switch has its contacts open and does not conduct. An NPN transistor, therefore, is normally open as it does not conduct when the base is held at 0 V.

An easier way to think of the NPN switch is that of an inverter. When the input is high the output is low. When the input is low the output is high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmpX3r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An NPN inverter.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsWt0s.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A double-inversion gives a buffer.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fekot5.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. A  PNP inverting buffer.*

This circuit works provided the logic input is working on the same V+ as the transistor.

Comment: Yes, probably I got confused with the terminology. But I think you got an idea what I'm trying to achieve here with the transistor. Btw updated the question.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: In my case logic input is working on a different V+ than transistor. Is this a problem?

Comment: Yes. The NPN will work because it is referenced to the ground. The NPN won't. That's why NPNs are so often used for level shifting between different supply voltages.

Comment: Is this the only way achieve this I mean by using 2 NPN transistors as in Fig 1.? I do not have much space left for this... Is there any other options?

Comment: Your question doesn't explain the problem you are trying to solve.  Hit the edit link. Its bedtime in Ireland.

Comment: Fig 1. already solves my problem and it's a correct answer to my question. The problem is that this inverter would take to much space if I would use 2 separate regular NPN transistors. Luckily I found that I can use a Darlington transistor in SOT-23 package in this case unless you have other suggestions.

Comment: @user1258202: a Darlington NPN transistor still inverts, same as a plain NPN, so it won't work as Transistor's two-transistor circuit.  Compare the internal connections of a Darlington to the two-transistor circuit above.

Comment: @Transistor Your figure 3 is just as much of an inverter as figure 1.

Comment: @PeterBennett your're right, a Darlington NPN transistor won't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Fixed, thanks, @Hearth. It was bedtime!

Comment: @Transistor can I use something like that to save the space? https://www.rohm.com.tw/datasheet/VT6X12/vt6x12

Comment: This is a different question so it's not appropriate to drag on the discussion here. In any case the internal diagram shows that it is two transistors with the collector of one connected to the base of the other. It's not clear how you think this could be used. You can post that as a new question with a screengrab of the internal circuit and a schematic of how you think it could be used.